# System.ArgumentException when building SSIS project in Azure DevOps. Works locally

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssis, azure-devops, devops

When I build an SSIS project in Azure DevOps I get the following error:

> System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected
>   range.    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Interop.ProjectInterop.ReferencePackage(Package
>   package, String packageLocation)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.PackageItem.Load(IDTSEvents events)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.PackageItem.get_Package()    at
>   Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DataTransformationsProjectBuilder.IncrementalBuildThroughObj(IOutputWindow
>   outputWindow)    at
>   Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DataTransformationsProjectBuilder.BuildIncremental(IOutputWindow
>   outputWindow)

It's not obvious to me which value this is that is not falling within the expected range, and it seems like I can't get any more detailed information from Azure DevOps. The project builds successfully locally.

I'm using the [SSIS Build & Deploy component](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TG.VSTS-SSIS) to build the project . I've also tried to use devenv.com via Command Prompt to build it, with the same results.

Do you know what this could be or at least how I can access more helpful logs?

And a side question: The project, that builds in few seconds locally, is taking from 12 - 25 minutes to build in Azure DevOps. Do you know why that is?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you get this issue resolved? I see that a solution was proposed to your post on developercommunity.visualstudio.com: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/478293/systemargumentexception-when-building-ssis-project.html

Answer (score -1):

I am not saying this the answer to the question, **however** I am adding my experience so that it might help someone else.

I had similar issue today morning. At least, the error was exactly the same.
I had a SQL Server connection which was not accessible due to network issue.  After fixing the network issue the problem got resolved.

(I also had converted sql connection from package level to project level. I removed that and reconverted to project level. Not sure if had anything to do the resolution of the issue)